# Simple jQuery show(); hide(); confusion

Tags: jquery, fancybox, show-hide

I have this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    $(".one-edition img").hover(function() {
        $(this).next(".editions-info-text").show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).next(".editions-info-text").hide();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Which, if the image under the div one-edition is hover'd over it shows the info text div, and when hovered out, it disappears - easy.

However, I'm trying to get it to work using the Fancybox gallery like so:

```
<div class="grid_3 one-edition">
    <a href="images/latest/MO20.jpg" rel="editions-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x250"></a>
    <a href="images/latest/MO20.jpg" rel="editions-1"></a>
    <a href="images/latest/MO20.jpg" rel="editions-1"></a>
        <div class="editions-info-text">
            <p>Title of edition</p>
            <p>Further information</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

The gallery works fine, but the editions-info-text is no longer showing or hiding. It must be something to do with wrapping the img in the anchor tag, but I've been trying to mess around with it for a while now and felt you guys might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from `$(this).next(".editions-info-text").show();`. $(this) should be the image element, but `next()` means to find the image's siblings, but the `.editions-info-text` is not in its siblings. You need to rewrite the selector query a little bit.

Comment: Thanks - this makes perfect sense. Do you know if there's any way for it to select the next div, rather than the next element?

Comment: Hi @Grace, but if the code now looks like this, what's best to use:

`<div class="grid_3"><div class="one-edition">
<a href="product-1.php"><img src="images/editions/1_Right_To_Buy_295.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="editions-info-text">
   <p>Right To Buy</p>
   <p>C-type Print</p>
  </div>
 </div>`

Comment: There are many ways to do it: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.editions-info-text')` or `$(this).parent().parent().siblings('.editions-info-text')` or `$(this).parents('.one-edition').siblings('.editions-info-text')`

Comment: Thanks, Grace. I understand how this is laid out now. Thanks for your help again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use parent() to move up to the `<a>` that you added. Then proceed as you did before.

```
(function() {
     $(".one-edition a img").hover(function() {
         $(this).parent('a').next(".editions-info-text").show();
     },function(){
         $(this).parent('a').next(".editions-info-text").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The combination of yours, and @Grace Shao's below worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed the structure of your html, the `next()` jQuery API is returning another element.

```
.editions-info-text
```

is not the next element to the image, so you would need to rebuild your script this way:

```
$(function() {
    $(".one-edition img").hover(function() {    
     $(this).parent().parent().find('.editions-info-text').show();
   //$('.one-edition').find(".editions-info-text").show();
        },function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().find('.editions-info-text').hide();
   //$('.one-edition').find(".editions-info-text").hide();
    });
});
```

**update**
after the proper observations made by @grace shao, the edited code above will work

Comment: this would not work, because `$('.one-edition')` will return all the elements with the class `.one-edition`, but not the one associated with `$(this)`. It is possible there are more than one `$('.one-edition')`